# Create dropdownlist from enum and bind data to EF model property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enumdropdownlistfor

I am trying to bind dropdownlist selected value to the model property and after multiple tries, I am not able to figure out what could be wrong here.

I want to understand how is that upon form submit, the user selected value from the dropdownlist will fill in the property of EF model. Where `model.tblPickup.LocationList` is an ENUM and `model.tblPickup.LocationType` is an EF model property.

**MVC (razor) code**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tblPickup.LocationType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.tblPickup.LocationList, "Select Address Type", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tblPickup.LocationType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tblPickup.LocationType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tblPickup.LocationType, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(WBusiness.Models.LocationTypes))), "Select Address Type", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tblPickup.LocationType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Code Behind - It's a composite model with three classes:**

```
//Actual class creatd by EF
    public partial class tblLocation
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string LocationName { get; set; }
            public string OtherDetails { get; set; }
            public Nullable<decimal> Latitude { get; set; }
            public Nullable<decimal> Longitude { get; set; }
            public string GoogleLink { get; set; }
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> LocationType { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateDate { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> ProfileId { get; set; }
            public Nullable<bool> Deleted { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeleteDate { get; set; }

            public virtual tblProfile tblProfile { get; set; }
        }

//Partial class to add custom property
    public partial class tblLocation
        {
            public LocationTypes LocationList { get; set; }
        }

//ENUM class
    public enum LocationTypes
        {
            Pickup = 1,
            Delivery = 2
        }
//Composit class with order and location in it
        public class OrderDetailModel
            {
                public tblOrder tblOrder { get; set; }
                public tblLocation tblPickup { get; set; }
            }
//Controller code
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(OrderDetailModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.tblOrders.Add(model.tblOrder);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

When I try to submit the form. I am getting the following error:
1. For the first dropdown: Although the field is an integer type, I reach code behind, however,**ModelState.IsValid** is **false**.
2. For the second dropdown code: I get "The field Location Type must be a number." Which makes sense because Location Type is an integer field.

Comment: Please show your controller code.

Comment: You need to cast `int` received to your `enum` type.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I can cast it, but that would be manually and I will have to bypass `ModeState.IsValid`. BTW controller code added.

Answer (score 0):

This is working example from a site I recently developed. The `EnumDropdown` is used in a loop.

```
//models
public enum SystemDocType
{
    [Display(Name = "Other")]
    Unknown,
    [Display(Name = "Condominium Certification")]
    CondominiumCertification,
    [Display(Name = "Previous Fiscal Years Ending Income/Expense")]
    PrevYearsIncomeExpense,
    [Display(Name = "Reserve Study")]
    ReserveStudy
    //more
}
public class DocumentType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "System Doc Type")]
    public SystemDocType? SysDocType { get; set; }
    //more
}

//controller
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("condo/updatedoctype")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateDocType(FormCollection data, int itemid)
{
    var docType = context.DocTypes.Where(t => t.Id == itemid).FirstOrDefault();
    if (docType != null)
    {
        string val = data["item:" + itemid.ToString() + ":name"];
        int sysType = int.Parse(data["item:" + itemid.ToString() + ":sysdoctype"]);
        docType.TypeName = val;
        docType.SysDocType = (SystemDocType)sysType;
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("DocTypes");
    }
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}

//.shtml (razor)
@model IEnumerable<fhaApproved2.Models.DocumentType>
@* more *@
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => item.SysDocType, 
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @Name = "item:" + @item.Id + ":sysdoctype" })
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" title="Update Document Type" formaction="/condo/updatedoctype" name="itemid" formmethod="post" value="@item.Id">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>
    </button>
}
```

Comment: I am using enum inside a class that is inside another class. This is the reason `ModelState.IsValid` is false.